# For loop run one time more

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I am going to write the codes to open a file and jump from headers (6 lines) and then in output file print time with 0.005 interval. number of rows should be the same as file that I opened. 
File that I have,has 16 rows but output file has 17. how can I make the for loop run 16?

I try to define the length of opened file but was not working.

thanks in advance.

Codes:

```
import time
from tkFileDialog import *
import Tkinter as T
import easygui as Ea
import pandas as pd
import numpy as N
import math as M   




name0= 'file.txt'



with open(name0, "r") as f:



    f.next() 
    f.next()
    f.next() 
    f.next()
    f.next() 
    f.next()

    fintime = fintime - 0.005

    for line in (f):



        fintime = fintime + 0.005

        numbers_str = line.split()

        numbers_float = [float(x) for x in ((numbers_str))]                       







        fName=name0+'new.txt'
        w1 = open(fName, "a")  
        w1.write("%s\n" % ((str(format(fintime, '.3f'))) ))            
        w1.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the for loop and remove manually the extra lap, like this:

```
for line in (f-1):

    fintime = fintime + 0.005
    numbers_str = line.split()
    numbers_float = [float(x) for x in [(numbers_str)-1]                       

    fName=name0+'new.txt'
    w1 = open(fName, "a")  
    w1.write("%s\n" % ((str(format(fintime, '.3f'))) ))            
    w1.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.I have the error like : _unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'file' and 'int'_